# Track sitecore campaign through email

Tags: exm, campaigncreator

I have a website which triggers email campaign on button click.

Now I have a requirement to create a sitecore campaign using campaign creator and need to add the id in the email campaign, when someone access the link through email that needs to be tracked.
Please suggest on how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you create and save the campaign in campaign creator, it will generate the Campaign link code. you can append this campaign link code to the url when you send the mail.

```
https://sitename/home?sc_camp=710**************************BA5
```

[image]